# How to extract JSX from class render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to write something like SCSS for React Native: it'll parse your component jsx and the special SCSS-like styles and return a usual RN component with reworked styles and jsx.

Lets say we have this react code:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>I remember syrup sandwiches</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Also I have SCSS-ish styles where every Text component inside the parent with a container "class" will have the same props that we provided.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  toRNStyles({
    container: {
      Text: { color: 'red' },
    },
  })
);
```

In the end we need the output of something like this:

```
...
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles._Text_container}>
    I remember syrup sandwiches
  </Text>
</View>
...
```

So how can I get the jsx that's returning from the render method from outside the class?

Comment: For what purpose do you need the output? You might use `render()` as @yoda suggested or wrap the component with a Higher-order Component if you needed to adjust at run-time. Also, the output isn't JSX (which is the syntax for using components) but rather a React Element (which is an object that describes the instance of a component)

Comment: why do you want to do this? Provide some context. Probably this not what you want to do, to solve your problem.

Comment: [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You want the jsx as a string literal?

Comment: @Chris yep, so I can parse it.

Comment: Parse them for what purpose? nvm, missed edit above

Answer (score 2):

You might write a plugin for babel, as react-native uses it to transform JSX to plain javascript.
Have a look to the these packages:

- babel-helper-builder-react-jsx
- babel-plugin-syntax-jsx
- babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
- babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source
- jsx-ast-utils

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a standard way of doing this. However, you could import ReactDOMServer and use its `renderToStaticMarkup` function.

Like this:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var myTestComponent = <Test>bar</Test>;
    console.dir(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(myTestComponent));
    
    return myTestComponent;
  }
}

const Test = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>foo</p>
      <span>{props.children}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom-server.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think parsing the returned element is the wrong approach. One challenge will be that the value of `style` will be an object (`styles.container` === a hash of style key/values) whereas you need a key which can be mapped to the object.

I think the most reusable approach is to leverage React context (which I'm assuming RN supports!) to build a `styleName` which can be augmented as you got down the component tree.

Here's an initial approach which makes a few assumptions (e.g. that every component will have `styleName` provided as a prop; you might want to provide that at design-time rather than run-time). In short, you wrap every component you want to participate with this HOC and the provide `styleName` as a prop to each component. Those `styleName` values are concatenated to produce contextualized names which are mapped to styles.

This example produces:

```
<div style="background-color: green; color: red;">
  <div style="color: blue;">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

```js
const CascadingStyle = (styles, Wrapped) => class extends React.Component {
  static displayName = 'CascadingStyle';
  
  static contextTypes = {
    styleName: React.PropTypes.string
  }
  
  static childContextTypes = {
    styleName: React.PropTypes.string
  }
  
  // pass the current styleName down the component tree
  // to other instances of CascadingStyle
  getChildContext () {
    return {
      styleName: this.getStyleName()
    };
  }

  // generate the current style name by either using the
  // value from context, joining the context value with
  // the current value, or using the current value (in
  // that order).
  getStyleName () {
    const {styleName: contextStyleName} = this.context;
    const {styleName: propsStyleName} = this.props;
    let styleName = contextStyleName;

    if (propsStyleName && contextStyleName) {
      styleName = `${contextStyleName}_${propsStyleName}`;
    } else if (propsStyleName) {
      styleName = propsStyleName;
    }

    return styleName;
  }
  
  // if the component has styleName, find that style object and merge it with other run-time styles
  getStyle () {
    if (this.props.styleName) {
        return Object.assign({}, styles[this.getStyleName()], this.props.styles);
    }

    return this.props.styles;
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <Wrapped {...this.props} style={this.getStyle()} />
    );
  }
};

const myStyles = {
  container: {backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'red'},
  container_text: {color: 'blue'}
};

const Container = CascadingStyle(myStyles, (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props} />
  );
});

const Text = CascadingStyle(myStyles, (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props} />
  );
});

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <Container styleName="container">
      <Text styleName="text">Some Text</Text>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```